# How to load and run a whole external js file after DOM loaded using GWT

Tags: gwt

I would like to load and run  an external js file after DOM loaded, the external js file like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/example.js"></script>
```

below is the onLoad hook:

```
 @Override
    protected void onLoad()
    {
        super.onLoad();
        //how to load and run the whole js file?
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`ScriptInjector`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.html), and don't forget [`setWindow`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.FromUrl.html#setWindow%28com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject%29)`(`[`TOP_WINDOW`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.html#TOP_WINDOW)`)`